# How to copy and paste multiple numbers into a column into INSERT INTO statements

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have many INSERT INTO statements which I need to populate (200 in total)

```
INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (1,3)
```

and so on...

However I don't want to manually enter up to 200 statements.

```
INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (1,200)
```

Is there a way I can copy and paste the Ids and drop them in after the ,? either in management studio or excel?

I've tried using "shift + alt" in management studio but this doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Tally and insert all the numbers in one go:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (200) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1)
SELECT 1, I
FROM Tally;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90136d99df08c50216b8f78acd68be63)

Comment: I upvoted. I find this useful to create data ad hoc.

Comment: Cheers @Larnu and BJones, this post could have been closed so thanks for your time and your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Excel solution. Useful for when you have actual data that you need to import - without using the import wizard.

```
ID  Field1  Concatenated
1   100     INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (1,100),
2   200     INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (2,200),
3   300     INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (3,300),
4   400     INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (4,400),
```

The function looks like:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO @TempTab (ID,field1) VALUES (",A2,",",B2,"),")
```